# Seagate 4TB external HD not seen by Linux Mint 18

Tags: usb, external-hdd

I've just bought a 4TB external HD from Seagate and want to use it as an extension to my laptop (Linux Mint 18). However it's not mounting automatically. Having searched several forums, I can't find a solution to this. I've tried addressing the HD in the terminal, but

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA SAMSUNG MZNLN256 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  25,0GB  25,0GB  primary   ext4            boot
 2      25,0GB  256GB   231GB   extended
 5      25,0GB  246GB   221GB   logical   ext4
 6      246GB   256GB   10,1GB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

doesn't show the HD.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bc2:231a Seagate RSS LLC
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 138a:0090 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 5986:0706 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 24ae:2010  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

After disconnecting, reconnecting and running:

```
$ dmesg | tail
[23864.763687] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[23877.666931] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[23877.688749] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=231a
[23877.688763] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[23877.688771] usb 2-1: Product: Expansion
[23877.688777] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Seagate
[23877.688782] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: NA8GVXYS
[23877.696566] scsi host5: uas
[23877.697684] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0707 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[23877.699718] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
```

and

```
$ sudo gnome-disks
```

just shows me the Model `Seagate Expansion (0707)` information, the Serial number and the Device `/dev/sdc`.

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc /media/disk4TB
```

tells me that it's not a valid block device.

Does anybody have an advice how to proceed in making it usable on Linux Mint18?

Comment: The Harddrive has a Partiontable ans is formated?

Comment: @Bahamut I can't tell. I just unpacked it, pluged it in and I don't know how to address it. Also **gparted** wasn't helping

Comment: Your `dmesg` above doesn't look right.

Comment: Maybe a Problem with the Modul uas `lsusb -v -d 0bc2:231a`  So we can write a quirk for your Harddrive.

Comment: `parted` is showing you the partitions on `sda`. You need to tell it which disk to view: `parted /dev/sdb`

Comment: Looks to me more like it's not mounting at all...have you run chkdsk on it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are still having problems with this, try:

```
# modprobe uas
```

I had a similar issue with what looks like the same drive. 
You can add uas to /etc/modules to automatically load it:

```
# cat /etc/modules

# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
uas
```

Comment: Note that you may need to wait a minute or two after doing this before the drive is recognized, so don't jump to immediate conclusions if you don't see it right away.